# Launch different activities from the same WidgetProvider in ListWidget

Tags: android, widget

I have a list widget and I want to launch differnt activities from different rows, but it always launch the activity that is in the PendingIntent, How can I do this? I  have the following codes:

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
            ....

        Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent();
             startActivityIntent.setClass(context, Principal.class);
        PendingIntent startActivityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, startActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.events_list, startActivityPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.events_list);         
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);
    }

    ....

}
```

In my WidgetFactory class

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

               ...

    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillIntent.setClass(mContext, Activity2.class);
    views.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.ll1, fillInIntent);

               ...
}
```

I want to start to start different activity depending to the row that i clicked (Row1-->Activity1, Row2-->Activity2...), but It always launchs the Principal activity.